# match multiple patterns and extract subpatterns into a array in perl

Tags: perl, design-patterns, pattern-matching, match

I have the following string in `$str`:

```
assign (rregbus_z_partially_resident | regbus_s_partially_resident | reg_two | )regbus_;
```

I want to parse this line and only capture all the string that starts with non-word character followed by either `reg_\w+` or `regbus_\w+` into an array.

so in the above example, i want to capture only 
`regbus_s_partially_resident` and `reg_two` into a array.

I tried this and it didnot work:

```
my (@all_matches) = ($str =~ m/\W(reg_\w+)|\W(regbus_\w+)/g);
```

Since i am trying to use `\W`, its copying the non-word character also into the array list, which i donot want.

Comment: so @all_matches should have

Comment: all_matches[0] is regbus_s_partially_resident
all_matches[1] is reg_two

Answer (score 2):

Need a little tweak to your regex

```
my @all_matches = $str =~ m/\W(reg_\w+|regbus_\w+)/g;
```

or

```
my @all_matches = $str =~ m/\W( (?:reg|regbus)_\w+ )/gx;
```

or even something along the lines of

```
my @all_matches = $str =~ m/\W( reg(?:bus)?_\w+ )/gx;
```

The most suitable form depends on what patterns you may need and how this is used.

Or, reduce the regex use to the heart of the problem

```
my @matches = grep { /^(?:reg_\w+|regbus_\w+)/ } split /\W/, $str;
```

what may be helpful if your strings and/or requirements grow more complex.

Answer (score 2):

> *its copying the non-word character also into the array list*

No, it doesn't.

```
$ perl -le'
   my $str = "assign (rregbus_z_partially_resident | regbus_s_partially_resident | reg_two | )regbus_;";
   my (@all_matches) = ($str =~ m/\W(reg_\w+)|\W(regbus_\w+)/g);
   print $_ // "[undef]" for @all_matches;
'
[undef]
regbus_s_partially_resident
reg_two
[undef]
```

But you do have a problem: You have two captures, so you will get two values per match.

Fix:

```
my @all_matches;
push @all_matches, $1 // $2 while $str =~ m/\W(reg_\w+)|\W(regbus_\w+)/g;
```

Far better:

```
my @all_matches = $str =~ m/\W(reg(?:bus)?_\w+)/g;
```

Ever better yet:

```
my @all_matches = $str =~ m/\b(reg(?:bus)?_\w+)/g;
```